# Images on mailItem to webbrowser

Tags: c#, image, outlook, mailitem

I would to show outlook mailitem (.msg) in webbrowser, i can do it this with HTMLBody property of mailitem, but this doesn't show images, this images in mailitem object are attachments,so, how can i put this attachments or mail images correctly in my webbrowser?

I'm Using Visual studio 2012 and c#.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the message in MHTML (olMHTML) format instead of olHTML.